# How to replace a string with ImageView in for loop , Logic needed

Tags: android, string

I have a string and I want to convert it to dots (and I made a picture that only contains one dot )

then I want to reveal some of my string but still want the rest of it to stay with that dot image!

i know how to do this without using an ImageView,
 and here's how i do it:

```
String txt = "Hello World";
String show = "Hel";
char[] chr =  txt.toCharArray();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x=0; x<chr.length; x++)
    {


        if(x >= show.length() && !Character.isWhitespace(chr[x])) {

                // Here is where i want to show my (dot Image) instead 
                stringBuilder.append("*");

        }
        else
           stringBuilder.append(chr[x]);
    }

  TextView textview - findViewById(R.id.textView);
  textview.setText(stringBuilder);
```

but instead of doing this :

```
stringBuilder.append("*");
```

I'm trying to use an ImageView? it's very small (same dot size)
is that even possible ? thinking about the space between words and the TextView in my layout! it's kinda hard.

check this picture it will explain it clearly

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving you a solution with slightly different approach you don't need to use image view for that If you have (same dot size) Image View. There is a character on keyboard I don't know how to pronounce it but it looks like this **"•"** .
you can change the color of the particular string in the text with the help of SpannableStringBuilder. And you can Set the color you want to set.

**Use SpannableStringBuilder and create a SpannableString :**

```
SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("•");
str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YOUR_COLOR), 0, str1.length(), 0);
builder.append(str1);
```

After that set your text like this :

```
textview.setText( builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Your code will look like :**

```
String txt = "Hello World";
String show = "Hel";
char[] chr =  txt.toCharArray();

SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    for (int x=0; x<chr.length; x++)
{
    if(x >= show.length() && !Character.isWhitespace(chr[x])) {
        // Here is where you need to append the dot.
        SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("•");
        str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YOUR_COLOR), 0, str1.length(), 0);// Use Your COLOR (Orange).
        stringBuilder .apend(str1);
    }
    else
        stringBuilder.append(chr[x]);
}

TextView textview - findViewById(R.id.textView);
textview.setText( stringBuilder , TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

> I haven't tested it... Give it a try and tell me if it works ...

Comment: **• (BULLET) UTF-8 character**  : ASCII value: 8226. Unicode: U+2022. HTML: &#8226; Name: BULLET CSS: \2022 ? BULLET in other fonts.

Comment: That's Amazing! i didn't know about SpannableString class! your idea has completely solved my problem man! thank you so much for that! i will try to understand this SpannableString more and more. thank you

Comment: do you suggest a new title for this question ?